# Create new column with 4 values and split existing value from table 4 ways

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I want to create a new column called "Quarters" and then for every line in my existing table create 4 new lines with 1,2,3,4 inserted as the quarters and then divide the field "FPAYG_Quota" by 4 to now make that a quarter quota

```
SELECT 

1 as Quarter,
FP.ClientOffice,
FP.FPAYG_Quota

FROM `commercial-analysis.2022_AM_Territory.FPAYG_Quotas` as FP
```

[image: Here's a before and after]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it is considered bad taste to use images to present data - rather use text - so we can help you then

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I tried to create a table but the formatting was off so I thought a table might be easier, sorry

Comment: Oh, Ok. at least you tried! you should try again. meantime, see my answer :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select ClientOffice, Quarter, FPAYG_Quota / 4 as FPAYG_Quota
from your_table, 
unnest([1,2,3,4]) Quarter
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 'Client A' ClientOffice, 100 FPAYG_Quota union all 
  select 'Client B', 200
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, Thanks very much :D